# Codenameone:Not able to add new skins on emulator

Tags: codenameone

I wan t to test my application on all devices with emulator but currently i have only on skin(device) to test. so I just want to add more skins on my emulator then i can test my application in multiple device skins
   Can you please let me know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Simulator, Navigate to `Skins -> More...` another View will turn up and here you can select and download Skins.

Comment: Make sure you defined the proxy settings correctly under the Network menu in the simulator.